# Conversion void* (char* without \0) to std::string

Tags: c++, stl

I need to convert const void* (that points to c-string without '/0') to std::string.

I have function "function":

```
void function(const void* ptr, size_t size);
```

There is a call:

```
...
std::string x("abcd");
function(x.data(), x.size());
...
```

How can I change the first parameter to std::string in 'function'?

(I know it looks weird. I've written simple example. I'd like to ask about conversion.)

Comment: I don't understand, why not just pass `x` and change the prototype ?

Comment: `void function(std::string)`?

Comment: It's just a stupid example but I need do this conversion. I cannot change the prototype. I don't want to write about details and paste real unreadable code.

Comment: I'd like to ask how to do a conversion. It's just a example. Please assume that I can't change the prototype.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type-cast the `void*` and pass both values to the `std::string` constructor:

```
void function(const void* ptr, size_t size)
{
    std::string s(static_cast<const char*>(ptr), size);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does `static_cast<const char*>` work well with `const void*`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Yes, as long as it started out appropriately (i.e., not a `double *` or anything).

Comment: @chris OK, I just wasn't sure about the `void*` case, `static_cast<const char*>()` is preferable of course.

Answer (score 3):

> *"How can I change the first parameter to std::string in 'function'?"*

```
void function(const void* ptr, size_t size) {
    std::string str((const char*)ptr,size);
}
```

should work.

Comment: Boo for the lazy cast.